# awk command in bash script replaced my file field separator from ":" to " "

Tags: bash, awk, field, separator

This is how my BookDB.txt file looks like:

```
Red:Blue:12:197:101
```

I entered this command into the prompt:

```
awk -F: '$1=="Red"{$2="Black"}1' BookDB.txt >> tmp && mv tmp BookDB.txt
```

And this is the changes to my file:

```
Red Black 12 197 101
```

The problem is that I want the command to preserve the field separator as ":" but the command changes the field separator to the white space. The only field that I want to change is the second field called "Blue" to "Black". Is there any way for me to preserve the separator as ":"?

This is the result I wanted:

```
Red:Black:12:197:101
```

EDITS:

```
read -p "Title of the old book: " title
read -p "Title of the book you want to update: " title_Update

awk -F: -vOFS=":" '$1=="$title"{$1="$title_Update"}1' BookDB.txt
```

Comment: `-vOFS=":"` should do it, in future please consult the man page which clearly describes this.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But if I were to replace the "Red" and "Black" with variables, it doesn't. Is there any reason why?

Comment: show an example of what you mean.

Comment: I posted an example on the edits column.

Comment: You can't use shell variables inside an awk script. Convert them to awk vairables by using `-vTitle="$title"` etc. Again this can be learned by just searching for you problem E.g "how to use shell variables in awk"

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! Noted!

Comment: Note that by not leaving a space between -`v` and the variable name you are making your script completely unnecessarily gawk-specific. Just use `-v var=val`, not `-vvar=val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign a value to a field you are telling awk to recompile the current record using the current OFS value to replace the FS value that was used when the record was read. You want:

```
awk -v old="$title" -v new="$title_update" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} $1==old{$1=new} 1'
```

The reason the above way of setting FS and OFS is the right way is that when initing 2 variables that MUST be set to the same hard-coded value, for clarity and future maintainability it's best to init them at the same time to that value instead of initing them independently to the same value in completely separate parts of the code.

It also makes a lot more sense to init variables at the start of the script, i.e. before they are used, instead of at the end of the script after they're used.

Answer (score 0):

Use OFS:

```
awk -F":" '$1=="Red"{$2="Black"}1'  OFS=":" file
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OFS (output field separator) predefined AWK variable. Th initial value of this variable is " " and that is the reason why you are getting space in between your output. See below different methods to use OFS variable.

```
[root@saltmaster test]# awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFS=":"}$1=="Red"{$2="Black"}1' input.txt
Red:Black:12:197:101
[root@saltmaster test]# awk -v FS=":" -v OFS=":" '$1=="Red"{$2="Black"}1' input.txt
Red:Black:12:197:101
[root@saltmaster test]# awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"; OFS=":"}$1=="Red"{$2="Black"}1' input.txt
Red:Black:12:197:101
[root@saltmaster test]# awk -F":" '$1=="Red"{$2="Black"}1'  OFS=":" input.txt
Red:Black:12:197:101
```